# Im trying to disable/enable a dropdown when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, dropdown

Im trying to disable/enable a dropdown box once a button is clicked. I tried the following but it's not working:

```
function disable() {
  document.getElementById('room').disabled=true;
}
function enable() {
  document.getElementById('room').disabled=false;
}
```

My dropdown is inside a `<?php?>` which is this:

```
print "<select  class=\"no_of_room\"name=\"qtyroom".$sub_row2['room_id']."\"  
id=\"room".$sub_row2['room_id']."\" 
onChange=\"selection(".$sub_row2['room_id'].")\" style=\"width:100%; 
color:black; height:45px;\">\n";
print "<option value=\"0\">0</option>\n";
$i = 1;
while($i <= $sub_row2['total_room'])
{
 print "<option value=\"".$i."\">".$i."</option>\n";    
 $i = $i+1;
 }
 print "</select>\n";
```

Then

```
print "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"enable()\" value=\"Enable list\">";
print "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"disable()\" value=\"Disable list\">";
```

Comment: `getElementById('room')` doesn't match `id=\"room".$sub_row2['room_id']."\"` (which would be `room1`, `room2`, etc.

Comment: In what way is it failing?  Is the problem happening in the server-side code or the client-side code?  Basically, if this PHP code is producing the exact output to the browser that you expect then remove the PHP code from the question and focus on the client-side code if that's where the problem is.  When you debug, what happens?  Is there an error in your browser's debugging console?  Are the functions invoked?  What happens?

Answer (score 0):

Your enable/disable functions are trying to work with element id "room" while your select element id has something attached to it `room".$sub_row2['room_id']`

In order for this to work IDs have to be the same.

Comment: Tried changing the id into room.$sub_row2['room_id'] but it still doesn't work.